# textFormField focus node doesn't properly work in listView

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of form where I can input different data like as firstname, lastname, dateOfBirth,age etc. I used a listBuilder for this. My problem is that, when I click on submit button then empty textFormField is not properly focus/my cursor is not going that empty textFormField. I text another way, In ListViewBuilder it doesn't work but if I use one form then it works. Dynamically in ListViewBuilder is doesn't work.

please give a proper solution that if there is any empty field in textFormField in listView then my cursor will move that empty textFormField.

I tried in single form. it works fine but in ListViewBuider it doesn't work

Comment: ListViewBuilder dispose invisible item, for form case, you can stick with SingleChildScrolView for this.